# How to populate a column of tableB with distinct values from TableA?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have two tables that look something like this:

TableA

| id | product_type | product | morecolumns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | widgets | widget_modelA | somedescription |
| 2 | widgets | widget_modelB | somedescription |
| 3 | whatsits | whatsit_mobelX | somedescription |
| 4 | whatsits | whatsit_mobelY | somedescription |

etc...

TableB

| id | product_type | Product_type Description | morecolumns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | widgets | Widgets are products that... | otherdetails etc |
| 2 | whatsits | whatsits are products that... | otherdetails etc |

etc...

TableB is currently empty and tableA is populated.

What I would like to do is fill the product_Type column of tableB with unique values from TableA's product_Type column so that it looks like the above tableB example.

I only need to fill in this one product_type column for now, I can set the other columns in tableB to accept empty/null values for the sake of the query and fill the other columns in later manually, but TableA is large and too impractical to compile the unique list manually without introduciung human error and missing some.

I'm sure there is some kind of terminology for this table relationship but I'm not sure what it is, so this makes searching harder.

Can anyone give me an example of the query I need to use to do this?

Edit: Also, for clarity, rather than a one off query, I am also happy to do this if there is some way of linking these two talbes in phpmyadmin, so the two columns are kept in sync in some way. (if the other columns are empty/null or have default values in them in tableB, that is OK, I can deal with that on the front end)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think I was trying to make it harder than it needed to be with sub-queries in brackets etc. What worked for me in the end was:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (product_type) 
SELECT
    product_type
FROM
    tableA
GROUP BY
    product_type
```

I suppose this still does not answer the other aspect of the question with the linking tables, which I'm still not sure how to do, or if I need a totally different schema for that etc, but it's gets me moving in the direction I need for now.